# C++ class constructors qualified as __attribute__((pure)) or __attribute__((const))

Tags: c++, attributes, pure-function

Can and should C++ class constructors be declared `__attribute__((pure))` if they only can reach data via its parameters? And in which cases should they be qualified as `__attribute__((const))`?

Comment: Err, what's the point? When will an average well-formed program going to invoke a c'tor for the same object twice?

Comment: Ahh, I didn't think of the fact that it creates/allocates a new instance. I guess it's not relevant to qualify constructors then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC warns when you qualify constructors as `pure` or `const`. This is because a constructor does not return anything (returns `void`) and it does not make much sense to have a `pure` or `const` attributes on such functions.

See godbolt demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1xeQYb).

```
<source>:3:30: warning: 'pure' attribute on function returning 'void' [-Wattributes]
     A()  __attribute__((pure));

                              ^
<source>:8:31: warning: 'const' attribute on function returning 'void' [-Wattributes]
     B()  __attribute__((const));                               ^
```

From GCC [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html):

> **const**
>   ...
>   Because a const function cannot have any side effects it does not make sense for such a function to return void. Declaring such a function is diagnosed.
>
> **pure**
>   ...
>   Because a pure function cannot have any side effects it does not make sense for such a function to return void. Declaring such a function is diagnosed.